# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table customer

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I get this error every time I try and implement hibernate with my spring booty application. I don't know if it's an issue with mySQL commands. I'm using maven dependencies, tried everything I know...no results. Please help

```
    enterorg.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table customer (id integer generated by default as identity, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:442) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at com.martinnnachi.springdemo.WebCustomerTrackerApplication.main(WebCustomerTrackerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by default as identity, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name v' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:768) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:653) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:193) ~[tomcat-dbcp-10.0.14.jar:10.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:193) ~[tomcat-dbcp-10.0.14.jar:10.0.14]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

My entity class is below. I've gone through every line of code to ensure the annotations are correct

```
codepackage com.martinnnachi.springdemo.entity;


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Customer() {

    }
}
```

My application.properties file. Not sure if I missed something

```
 enter cospring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#datasource configurations-
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# DDL generation
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC"
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.martinnnachi.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-customer-tracker</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.14</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my bean config class, initially i had issues with the session factory bean creation but i believe this solved that issue:

```
package com.martinnnachi.springdemo.config;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource( dataSource() );
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.martinnnachi.springdemo.entity" );
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties( hibernateProperties() );

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName( "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" );
        dataSource.setUrl( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC" );
        dataSource.setUsername( "springstudent" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "springstudent" );

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop" );
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" );

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

Not sure what else i missed. been pulling my hair out all day! i would appreciate any help offered

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

add this to your application.properties file